# Laravel Linux php artisan can't open

Tags: php, linux, laravel, centos

I'm having some problems with installing my app on vps server with ssh2_connection.
I have created library to configure and automatically install laravel project on any vps (apache, mariadb, mysql, php, phpmyadmin..), but now I have one last problem, running php artisan like `cd /var/www && php arisan key:generate`, and every time it says like:

> Could not open input file: arisan

Ofcourse when I open console in putty it will work, but with php function I had no success.
My function looks like:

```
public static function installLaravel($connection){
        $cmds = array (
            'cd /var/www && php arisan migrate',
            'cd /var/www && php arisan db:seed',
            'cd /var/www && php arisan passport:install',
        );

        foreach ($cmds as $cmd) {
            $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $cmd);
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
            echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);
            echo stream_get_contents($stream);
        }
    }
```

I tried to add  `cd ~/var/www` or  `cd /var/www` before running php artisan commands, but it will always set route to `root` directory.

I even tried to run like `php /var/www/sitea/artisan migrate` still same problem

BTW: I'm testing on Centos 8

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's called `artisan` (you're missing a t), not `arisan`.

```
$cmds = array (
    'cd /var/www && php artisan migrate',
    'cd /var/www && php artisan db:seed',
    'cd /var/www && php artisan passport:install',
);
```

Comment: OMG I can't believe I lost last hour wondering what is the problem. Probably 12h programing today is enough. Thank you! :)

Comment: You're welcome :). Consider marking my answer as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: also shorten your code. `php /var/www/artisan migrate`